I need to zip a report folder in cypress
I am working on uploading the test results to Xray using JIRA API. I am already generating the cucumber-html report in my project directory and could call JIRA upload API for uploading single file. However, I need to upload the whole html report for which I need to zip report folder to upload via API. I tried couple of available solution with javascript to zip my report folder at project directory but none of them are helping. can anyone help to solve this problem?
I need to store the zipped folder in the same directory and without browser

I tried the solution posted there. but looks like it's not applicable along with Cypress. the package informed BlobWriter, couldn't find or resolve errors around it

I need to store the zipped folder in the same directory and without browser - what does this mean it does not seem to be a proper sentence.

Also please add details of what is not working.

You probably just add a task to perform the zip.
For example see zip-lib
on('task', {
  zipFile({pathToFile, pathToZip}) {
    const zl = require("zip-lib");
    zl.archiveFile(pathToFile, pathToZip)
  },
  zipFolder({pathToFolder, pathToZip}) {
    const zl = require("zip-lib");
    zl.archiveFolder(pathToFile, pathToZip)
  }
})

Using an object to pass parameters since task only takes one argument.
after(() => {
  cy.task('zipFile', {
    pathToFile: 'path/to/file.txt', 
    pathToZip: 'path/to/target.zip'
  })
})

